# Using pyinstaller on a script the imports unidecode

Tags: python

I'm trying to use PyInstaller on a script that imports unidecode. Unidecode itself conditionally imports its character tables in its `__init__.py`

```
try:
    table = Cache[section]
except KeyError:
    try:
        mod = __import__('unidecode.x%03x'%(section), [], [], ['data'])
    except ImportError:
        Cache[section] = None
        continue   # No match: ignore this character and carry on.
```

PyInstaller warns about the **import** hack, but I can't find a way to tell it to make use of the 188 character tables (x000.py to x099.py) in the unidecode directory.

The final .exe runs fine, yet the Unicode characters are not converted they simply disappear.

Can anyone help me to get PyInstaller to recognize the character tables?